# Прямая речь или обычное предложение

Tags: пунктуация

1. Какие необходимо знаки пунктуации расставить в приведенных ниже предложениях и расскажите, пожалуйста, почему именно так?
2. Являются ли в 1 предложении "слово мяч" и во 2-ом предложении "мяч" прямой речью?

Он сказал слово мяч.
Он сказал мяч.
Он сказал: "отличный мяч".

Answer (score 2):

Он сказал слово "мяч". В кавычки берем то слово, которое он назвал. Мы как бы цитируем его, поэтому ставим кавычки. Это предложение без прямой речи.
Он сказал: "Мяч". Это предложение с прямой речью,которая представлена словом,что он произнес.
Он сказал: "Отличный мяч!" Здесь вновь прямая речь, передающая точно те слова, которые он произнес, и даже интонацию.